# $f(x)$ is differentiable and defined over $[0,2]$, $f(0)=1$ and $f(x)\leq 0\rightarrow f'(x)>0$. Then:

Tags: functions

> $f(x)$ defined over $[0,2]$, $f(0)=1$ and $f(x)\leq 0\rightarrow
> f'(x)>0$. Then:
>
> a) $f(x)\leq 0$ for some $x$ in the interval $[0,2]$
>
> b) $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$ in the interval $[0,2]$
>
> c) $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ in the interval $[0,1]$
>
> d) $f(x)$ is strictly positive for all $0<x<1$ and $f(x)$ is strictly
>   negative for all $1<x<2$

I can't figure this out. I don't even know where to begin or else I would have showed my working. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Is $f$ continuous on $[0,2]$ and differentiable on $(0,2)$?

Comment: Yes, it is differentiable.

Comment: One more question, What is the purpose of this problem? Find examples safisfying following conditions, or prove/disprove statements?

Comment: We need to pick the correct option from a,b,c and d. It's a multiple choice question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constant function $f(x)=1$ is a counterexample for (a) and (d).

Since $f(0)=1$, (c) is obviously false.

It remains to show (b) is true. Suppose $f(x)<0$ for some $x\in[0,2]$. Then the minimum of $f$ is negative. What's the derivative at a point of minimum, if this point is in $(0,2)$? Can you do the case when the minimum is at $2$?

Answer (score 1):

If the minimum of $f$ is at $0$, then there's nothing to prove. So let's suppose that the minimum of $f$ is attained at some $a \in (0,2]$. Suppose that $f(a) < 0$. By continuity, there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that $f(x) < 0$ for all $x \in (-\epsilon + a, a)$. We have $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x \in (-\epsilon + a, a)$, so $f$ is strictly increasing on this interval, hence $f\left( -\frac{\epsilon}{2} + a\right) > f(a)$, a contradiction. Therefore, $f(a) \ge 0$ and so $f\ge 0$ on $[0,2]$.